# How can the word "agreeable" describe a person who easily agrees with s.b. or s.th.?

Tags: grammaticality

The word *agreeable* is used to describe a character trait of people who "easily agree" on things, e. g. people who rarely insist in their own opinion. In the form of *agreeableness*, it is also used in psychology as one of the [big five personality traits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Five_personality_traits). People with high agreeableness are often altruistic, people with low agreeableness may be perceived as selfish.

One specific example, where I most often heard the word being used, is in the context of salaray negotiation, where [*agreeable* people accept lower salaries more easily than *disagreeable* people](https://www.pon.harvard.edu/daily/negotiation-skills-daily/in-negotiation-how-much-do-personality-and-other-individual-differences-matter/). The words *agreeable* and *agreeableness* are used in the same context, e. g. in [this article](https://www.livescience.com/15575-nice-men-women-salary-agreeableness.html).

**How does it make sense that someone who easily agrees (e. g. to a lower wage, avoiding the conflict of demanding more) is agreeable?** To me the word clearly sounds like "it is easy to agree with that person", not "the person will easily agree with me".

(I recently heared another word that follows the same "logic", however I cannot remember it now. Maybe if someone can think of it or other words and point them out, the problem becomes clearer. It was another word where the person was described as *[something]able* in a context that suggested the person is *able to do or be something*.)

To me it would make more sense if the word *agreeing* would be used instead, because from my experience, adjectives with the ending *...able* describe subjects or objects with which something can be done.

Comment: Agreeable, to this old fart, means likable.

Comment: I agree with Mari-Lou. That does not make me agreeable.

Comment: @Mari-LouA What do you mean by "to this old fart"?

Comment: Is there something wrong with the question? It is interesting that likable may be a valid synonym, but it doesn't seem like the meaning I refered to. The meaning I described is "altruistic" or "empathic", which seems like the (logical, not semantic) opposite, i. e. someone who cares about others and their views, independent from whether these others like that person.

Comment: It is a disparaging self-deprecating comment about myself. The elderly, especially those who have a poor diet and lead sedentary lives, are known to fart (break wind) a lot.

Comment: Agreeable in that context is about people who are congenial, likable, affable and charming. It is easier for them to get along with others.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I agree, and that is how I would have understood it, but it seems like a different (maybe equally valid) meaning of the same word. I edited my question to include an example of how the word is used in the meaning that I refered to, specifically in the context of negotiations. In that context, it is rather a negative trait, so likable or charming does not fit.

Comment: You're thinking too hard about this. Is 'tall' positive or negative. Neither, it depends on context. Also, the concept of 'agreeableness' for personality is a technical label which may not be exactly the same as 'agreeable' (technical terms mean the technical idea, not the meaning of the informal term. Nearby but not identical)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Emissions no longer required for the label. Semantic ... drift. :)

Comment: @Mitch The trait is negative in the context because it causes worse outcomes. I agree that it depends on the context, but I think I made the context pretty clear. It is about negotiations (and similar situations), where an agreeable person (according to research often women) agrees with a lower wage more easily, while a disagreeing person (mostly extraverted men) are stricter in their negotiation. Regarding *agreeableness* vs *agreeable*, the terms are both used in the same context. I added another link to the question for an example.

Comment: @RaimundKrämer Your primary question is "How does it make sense for 'agreeable' to mean 'easily agrees with others'?" The answer is that that's just what the word means. Language isn't always compositional, isn't always reducible to the meaning of parts. 'Agreeable' doesn't mean literally 'able to agree'. It means what it means, and you just need to accept that. 'Awful' doesn't mean full of awe (it used to though), it means terrible. That's just what it is. You're trying to hold language to being always exactly literal and it often isn't.

Answer (score 3):

> **agreeable** *adjective*
>
> 1. Quite enjoyable and pleasurable; pleasant.
>    ‘a cheerful and agreeable companion’
> 2. *[predicative]* Willing to agree to something.
>    ‘they were agreeable to its publication’
>    [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/agreeable)

You can use *agreeable* to describe someone (definition 1) or their stance about a particular course of action (definition 2).

Describing a *person* as agreeable (definition 1) has nothing to do with whether they agree or even tend to agree to anything in particular. It is more helpful to say that the person 'agrees with' (doesn't violate) the sensibilities of others - i.e. that others would consider them 'nice'.

You ask:

> How does it make sense that someone who easily agrees is agreeable?

It doesn't, except to the extent that if someone tends to agree with you (definition 2), you may be more likely to consider them to be 'nice' (definition 1). However, that confuses definitions 1 and 2 quoted above.

Comment: Regarding definition 2: How does it make sense here? If they were agreeable, don't you say that they agreed?

Comment: @RaimundKrämer Definition 2 provides the 'agrees with' sense of *agreeable*. You can shorten "they were agreeable to the proposal" to just "they were agreeable", but that produces an ambiguous statement. If the shorter statement is interpreted with definition 1, it no longer carries the sense of the longer statement. My answer asserts that the two definitions carry very different senses. They might be easy to mix up, but it would be a mistake to do so.

Comment: I understand the different meanings, but where does the "able" come from? Why were they not just agreeing? Does it imply that they are given the *ability* to agree?

Comment: Verb and adjective forms are often different. If you want to use an adjective, you would usually use the adjective form rather than the verb form. E.g.: he *inflated* (verb) the ball. The ball was *inflatable* (adj). You can also say that the ball was *inflated* (verb), but that's not the same as saying that it is *inflatable*.

Comment: That is a good example. When I hear "the ball was inflatable", I expect that I (or someone) can inflate it. But if I am inflating the ball, am I *inflatable to the ball*, similar to definition 2 above? I think my main concern might come from the relation betwenn *...able* and *able to ...*, the former being somewhat "passive" and the latter "active" in the sense of expressing possibilites.

Comment: No. Aside from the subject-object order (you might get away with *the ball was inflatable by you*), *agreeable* may be a special case. Even the negation doesn’t work the same way: if he isn’t inclined to agree, you don’t say that he is **disagreeable*. You just say he *disagrees*.